# Can I recover Items from a deleted sprint?

Tags: azure-devops, recover, sprint, azure-boards

I´ve DELETED a Sprint by mistake and their related work items I went to the reclycle bin but I can't find those over there or the referred sprint. Has some one a solution or suggestion for me?

Answer (score 0):

### `<TL;DR>`

Work items aren't removed or deleted when deleting a sprint/iteration.

---

The Iteration field in Azure DevOps holds the Sprint value. When you delete an iteration, the Azure DevOps will ask what new iteration to assign the work items to. I think, by default, it assigns to the Team's Default Iteration:

[image]

[image]

The work items are still there, recreate the iteration if you want and move the items back into it.

---

If this isn't what you did, you may have removed the sprint from the Team's list of selected sprints.

[image]

If this is what happened, simply choose the <kbd>+ Select Iteration(s)</kbd> button to add it again:

[image]